# Trouble deleting ResourceMoverRG

Tags: azure, resource-management

Im trying to delete this and it just sits there running. I dont know what to do as this is a student account and if it doesn't delete, i could use up my entire allotment. Is there anything i can do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Nm9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting of resources can take some time, so wait for this process to either complete or fail. If it is still hanging after a couple of hours you will need to raise a support request with Microsoft. If you do not have a support contract you can raise a billing request which is free to everyone, as you are getting charged for resources you cannot delete. Support request can be raised through the Azure Portal.